# Mockito mocking won't work for this method. Am I doing something wrong?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I'm current using mockito 1.8.4 in this spring mvc application. Here is the code for the class/method I am trying to test.

```
public class CompleteTaskController implements IController {
    public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CompleteTaskController.class);

@Override
public void handle() {
    GUIFactory gf = new GUIFactory();
    IDatabasePullListOfUsers pull = new OraclePullListOfUsers();
    IDatabaseUserManagement manage = OracleUserManagement.getInstance();

    gf.makeGUI("completeTask", pull.pullAssignedRequests(GUIFactory.userLoggedIn));
    manage.completeTask(gf.getRequestID(), GUIFactory.userLoggedIn);
    gf.makeCustomGUI("Task has been completed");
    log.fatal(GUIFactory.userLoggedIn + " has completed the task of request id " + gf.getRequestID());
    gf.makeGUI("adminpanel");

}

}
```

so far, all the tests pass BUT the last one - which I just can't seem to understand why. Here is the code for my tests:

```
public class CompleteTaskControllerTest {

    @Test
    public void testHandleCallsMakeGUIAndPassesItPullAssignedRequestsAndAString(){
        CompleteTaskController mockCtc = mock(CompleteTaskController.class);
        GUIFactory mockGf = mock(GUIFactory.class);
        IDatabasePullListOfUsers mockPull = mock(OraclePullListOfUsers.class);

        mockCtc.handle();

        verify(mockGf).makeGUI("test", mockPull.pullAssignedRequests("test"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandleCallsCompleteTaskAndPassesItGetRequestIDAndAString(){
        CompleteTaskController mockCtc = mock(CompleteTaskController.class);
        IDatabaseUserManagement mockManage = mock(OracleUserManagement.class);
        GUIFactory mockGf = mock(GUIFactory.class);

        mockCtc.handle();
        when(mockGf.getRequestID()).thenReturn(1);

        verify(mockManage).completeTask(mockGf.getRequestID(),"Test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testHandleCallsMakeCustomGUIAndPassesItAString(){
        CompleteTaskController mockCtc = mock(CompleteTaskController.class);
        GUIFactory mockGf = mock(GUIFactory.class);

        mockCtc.handle();

        verify(mockGf).makeCustomGUI("test");
    }
}
```

Sorry for throwing all this code at you - the only test I am having issues with is the third test - which is trying to mock the gf.makeCustomGUI("Task has been completed") method!

Comment: Mmmh how do you get mockGf injected into mockCtc? I know only the way by annotations, or a manual way... Just an Idea...

Answer (score 1):

With the statement

```
verify(mockGf).makeCustomGUI("test");
```

are you trying to verify whether the "makeCustomerGUI" has been called with argument "test". And if that is your requirement, you can do that as below:

```
GUIFactory mockGf = mock(GUIFactory.class);
mockGf.makeCustomerGUI("test");
verify(mockGf).makeCustomGUI("test");
```

Once your mock object is created, Mockito will remember all invocations on it. So you can selectively verify the invocations.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, I'm trying to check whether the handle() methods calls mockGf.makeCustomGUI("anystringhere")

Comment: "GUIFactory gf" is local to the method, it's not a property of your "CompleteTaskController" object, so you can't test method invocations on "GUIFactory" while testing the "handle" method.

Comment: Why do Tests 1 and 2 successfully pass then? I thought it calls the handle method, and then verify checks to see if the methods were called!

Comment: This is very strange that your tests 1 and 2 are running successfully. In your first test method, you are verifying whether "mockGf.makeGUI" was called with the given arguments. But it was not called before your "verify" method execution, so it should fail.Again in your second method, you have "when(mockGf.getRequestID()).thenReturn(1)" which says "when mockGf.getRequestID() is called then return 1". Then you are verifying "mockManage.completeTask" method call, and this should again fail because there was no such method execution on your mock "mockManage" before "verify".Please try one by one